# Django: How can I organize common form submisson part into a function?

Tags: django

I'm creating a website. For my website, user can edit their profile on every page because there's a navbar and from edit profile section, form on modal appears.

So I'd like to organize this part into a function. But it seems difficult.

```
def index(request):
    if request.method != 'POST':
        profile_form = ProfileForm(instance=request.user)

    elif 'profile_form' in request.POST:
        profile_form = ProfileForm(instance=request.user, data=request.POST)

        if profile_form.is_valid():
            profile_form.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Your profile has been changed successfully.')
            return HttpResponseRedirect(request.path_info)

    context = {
        'profile_form': profile_form,
        #there are other contexts here
    }
    return render(request, 'site/index.html', context)
```

I mean I'd like to include this part on every views because user can edit page from every views. And I'd like to move the same part into somewhere.

```
def filter_entry(request):
    if request.method != 'POST':
        profile_form = ProfileForm(instance=request.user)

    elif 'profile_form' in request.POST:
        profile_form = ProfileForm(instance=request.user, data=request.POST)

        if profile_form.is_valid():
            profile_form.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Your profile has been changed successfully.')
            return HttpResponseRedirect(request.path_info)

    context = {
        'profile_form': profile_form,
        #there are other contexts here
    }
    return render(request, 'site/filter_entry.html', context)
```

My current code is like this. This is supposed to be a common behavior on every page so I'd like to organanize this into other function.

```
def edit_profile(request):
    if request.method != 'POST':
        profile_form = ProfileForm(instance=request.user)

    elif 'profile_form' in request.POST:
        profile_form = ProfileForm(instance=request.user, data=request.POST)

        if profile_form.is_valid():
            profile_form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(request.path_info)
```

I created `utils.py` and created this function inside it. And I tried like

```
def index(request):
    edit_profile(request)
    ...
    context = {
      'profile_form':profile_form, # However this view doesn't know what profile_form is
```

But ofc there is error because `profile_form` is not defined inside `index`

How can I organize code in this case?

Comment: "There is error" is a totally useless description of your problem. Please post the exact error message AND the full traceback.

Comment: I mean when I organize the common part into `edit_profile` function, the view `index` cannot know what the `profile_form` variable is because it's defined inside `edit_profile` function. So there is an error `profile_form is not defined`.

Comment: Please _edit your question_ to add those details. And actually, you're doing it wrong - your other views should not (and do not have to) know anything about profile edition, cf my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper way to handle this kind of problems without having to leak knowledge of this feature in each and every view of your site is a bit more complex (but much simpler to handle once it's done):

First, you want to write a view that handle the form submission (your `edit_profile` function is a good starting point) AND the matching url (so you can post to this url). In case of an invalid submission, it should render the appropriate template (the one used to render the form in the modal) so the user can correct the form and submit it again.

Then, you want to create a custom templatetag (an inclusion tag should be enough) that is responsible for creating the initial (unbound) form and render it. The HTTP form tag "action" attribute should point the above url and the form should have an hidden field containing the current url (so the `edit_profile` view can redirect to the right place after a successful submission.

Now you just have to use this custom templatetag in the relevant templates (if you use inheritance properly you should actually only need it in a couple base templates at most), and your other views don't have to know anything about profile edition anymore.

Comment: ah I forgot about templatetag. I will try to do your way. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Could you give me an example way to redirect to a page when templatetag returns `form`? I still don't get how to do it. I will update my question. Because templatetag returns `form`, it cannot include `HttpResponseRedirect` inside the templatetag.

Comment: I finally did it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

How about like this:

```
def index(request):

     profile_form = ProfileForm(request.POST or None, instance=request.user)

     if request.method == "POST":
        if profile_form.is_valid():
            profile_form.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Your profile has been changed successfully.')
            return HttpResponseRedirect(request.path_info)

    context = {
        'profile_form': profile_form,
        #there are other contexts here
    }
    return render(request, 'site/index.html', context)
```

Comment: Sorry I don't get what you did. I mean I'd like to use the common behavior (edit_profile) on every views. Sorry if I misundertstand something or question was hard to read.

Comment: Sorry I did not get your comment. But, what I did was I passed `instance` parameter with Form object initiation. Means it will generate a form(in html) with all the values of saved User (in both Get and Post). As I have passed instance in `POST` method, it will update the User values, will not create one.

Comment: Lets say you have 5 views with profile edit functionality, then you can use `profile_form = ProfileForm(request.POST or None, instance=request.user)` in each of them to have that edit functionality, rather than creating a new function for that.

Comment: Ah I see I think I get it and yes that's what I want to do. It would be better to organize code into a function because the quantity of the code is saved.